# Pass variable to .js file in asset

Tags: laravel, assets

I have a system in laravel, which calls a javascript chunk file.

```
@section ('provider-script')
  {{- Provider js files -}}
  <script src = "{{asset ('/ wzps / static / js / 2.4e3f1281.chunk.js')}}"> </script>
  <script src = "{{asset ('/ wzps / static / js / main.ff9c627f.chunk.js')}}"> </script>
@endsection
```

within those .js I need it to load in a certain part of the code a variable that would be the url that the user who executes it has in its database ...

How could I do it? try to do in the .js file

```
("http://www.google.com/");
```

and this works fine ... but I need something like ("http: // {{$ user-> website}} /");

my controller:

```
$user = Auth::user();
        return view('backend.index', compact('user'));
```

EDIT: i need put the user url INTO the .js file... not in a asset url :D

Part of my chunk file:

```
ie=a.n(ce).a.create({baseURL:"http://google.com/",withCredentials:!0})
```

i need replace the baseURL for the $user->website variable

Comment: You could try adding a script tag with a global variable containing that info, so in your blade file, something like `<script>const globalInfo = "http://{{$user->website}}/";</script>`

Comment: `<script src="{{ $user->web_site }}/wzps / static / js / 2.4e3f1281.chunk.js"></script>`

Comment: Hello guys! i need use $user->website into the .js file... not in the asset url.

Comment: you mean pass a PHP variable to the JS file?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this from meta tag.

```
<meta name="user-site" content="{{ $user->web_site ?? '' }}" />
```

In JS file, you can get this.

```
let user_site = document.querySelector("name['user-site']").content;
```

Or,
Using ajax request.
Hope it will helpful for you.